# cannot resolve symbol .text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)

Tags: java, android

```
    public void toast(String text) { 
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext().text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
```

> cannot resolve symbol 'text'

how i can solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

First you forget to close your `method` with `}`

```
  public void toast(String text) { 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext().text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
  }
```

And second mistake is

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()**,** text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

that  `Toast.makeText()`  method has three params `getApplicationContext`() , yourText, and `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` they must be separated by `,` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
public void toast(String text) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

`,` instead of `.` before `text`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error and are mixing the parameter with the app context.
there is no `Context.text` in android
it must be

```
public void toast(String text) { \
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and not

```
public void toast(String text) { 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext().text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```